# How do I render a component with multiple different props

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Here's a sample code:

Component

```
const DisplayContent = ({ data, type }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'header':
            return <h1 data-testid="header" data={data}></h1>
        case 'subtitle':
            return <h3 data-testid="subtitle" data={data}></h3>
        case 'paragraph':
            return <p data-testid="paragraph" data={data}></p>
        default: 
            return null
    }
}
```

Test file

```
describe('display content', () => {
    const { rerender } = render(
        <DisplayContent data={MockData} type="header" />
    )
    
    const propsList = [
        { data: MockData, type: "header" },
        { data: MockData, type: "subtitle" },
        { data: MockData, type: "paragraph" }
    ]
    
    propsList.forEach(prop => {
        rerender(<DisplayContent { ...prop } />)
    
        it(`should render ${prop.type}`, () => {
            expect(screen.queryByTestId(prop.type)).toBeTruthy()
        })
    })
})
```

When I run this code all the subsequent component render returns null. Is there a right way to render multiple components with different prop type?

Comment: It's being repeatedly re-rendered at test _discovery_ time. Why re-render at all; don't you just move the render into the actual tests?

Answer (score 0):

To correctly test rendering of a component with different props, you should place the `rerender` function and the assertions (it blocks) inside the `forEach` loop.

Here's a simplified version of your test code:

```
describe('DisplayContent', () => {
    const propsList = [
        { data: MockData, type: "header" },
        { data: MockData, type: "subtitle" },
        { data: MockData, type: "paragraph" }
    ];
    
    propsList.forEach(prop => {
        it(`should render ${prop.type}`, () => {
            const { rerender } = render(<DisplayContent {...prop} />);
            expect(screen.queryByTestId(prop.type)).toBeTruthy();
            rerender(null); // Optional: Clean up before next iteration
        });
    });
});
```